# sqlite3_bind_text replaces first char in string with NULL when used in function

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to pass a string to a function that uses `sqlite3_bind_text`. When I check the database, the first char of the string is replaced by a unicode NULL char (if I interpret the rectangle symbol containing four zeroes in each corner correctly).

Here is  a minimal example. The `cout` in the function outputs the string correctly, as does using `sqlite3_bind_text` directly in `main`.

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bind_string_to_statement(sqlite3_stmt *& statement, const string s)
{
    // These replace the first chars in first & second with [0000]...
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, s.c_str(), -1, nullptr);
    // ...although these look fine:
    cout << s.c_str() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    sqlite3 * db = nullptr;
    sqlite3_open("test.sqlite", &db);

    sqlite3_stmt * statement = nullptr;

    string query{ "create table if not exists t(c text primary key not null)" };
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, nullptr);
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    query = "insert or replace into t(c) values(?)";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, nullptr);
    string s{ "stuff" };

    // This fails as described in the function above...
    bind_string_to_statement(statement, s);

    // ...although this works fine:
//  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, s.c_str(), -1, nullptr);

    sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

What could be the problem when using `sqlite3_bind_text` in a function?

**/edit** The question may be a duplicate of the mentioned question regarding the solution but the symptoms of the problem manifested themselves so entirely different that I didn't find the other question when searching.

Comment: I suspect that the string is being deallocated before SQLite is done using it, since it's on the stack. Pass in `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` as the last argument to `sqlite3_bind_text` so that SQLite allocates its own copy.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yup, that's it, thanks! Please copy the comment into an answer so that I can accept it :)